# C++ adding an element to the array and resizing the array

Tags: c++

I am trying to add numbers one after the other to my array and so far I have this:

```
int main(){

    DynamicArray<int> intArray(5);
    int num = 0;
    int point;

    intArray.addElement(20);
    intArray.addElement(10);
    intArray.addElement(30);
    intArray.addElement(60);
    intArray.addElement(21);


    for(int x = 0; x < 5; ++x){
        intArray[x] = rand() % 100;
        std::cout << intArray[x] << " ";
    }


    std::cout << endl;

    std::cout << "\n" "Enter the number :" << endl;

    cin >> num;


    std::cout << "\n" "What point ?" << endl;

    cin >> point;

    for(int x = 0; x > point; --x){
        intArray[x] = intArray[x-1];
    }
    intArray[point] = num;

    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
        std::cout << intArray[x] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << endl;

    return 0;


}
```

but when I run it I get this:

```
7 49 73 58 30 

Enter the number :
2

What point ?
0
2 49 73 58 30
```

the question is how do I add the element 2 to position 0 without getting rid of the 7 and by resizing the array?

Thank you any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `DynamicArray`? And why would you prefer it over [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) ? See also [mcve], please.

Comment: Double check this loop: `for(int x = 0; x > point; --x)`

Comment: Is this [Embarcadero's `System.DynamicArray`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.DynamicArray)? Or some other library. Clarify.

Answer (score 0):

To resize the DynamicArray you need to **set the length properties** to the value you want, in your case `lenght + 1` to do this you can use this:

```
intArray.Length = intArray.Length + 1;
```

Then you can move and add your element as you want.
Pay attention to the index you use in the for cicle, it can contains some errors.

Note: For the code above, maybe is better to use the std::vector.

Comment: Even if you somehow magically knew what `DynamicArray` were, and even if it had a `Length` member, it is inconceivable that it would be a member _variable_ (rather than a setter function) because it would not be able to handle memory management in a sensible fashion. It looks like you just Googled the term and pulled this code from some other language. Please do clarify if this is not the case.

Comment: Actually, blow me, Turbo C++ has `DynamicArray` and [it _does_ work this way](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.DynamicArray). Blimey. Undid my downvote but you're still just guessing ;)